# How to cp or rm files based on ownership / permission

Tags: permissions, files, cp

After a problem with spam, I stopped `postfix`

```
postfix stop
```

and checked through the `mailq` manually to find hundreds of thousands of unsent spam.

The spam was sent from one of the sites hosted locally, and I know that user has not tried to send any emails since I stopped outgoing mail.

Therefore all the messages in `/var/spool/postfix/maildrop` that originate from that user on my machine are known to be spam, and I'd like to delete or move them to another dir for later investigation.

I would like to **move all the files with a given owner** (in this case the user 'web2') **from**

```
/var/spool/postfix/maildrop
```

**to**

```
/var/spool/postfix/temp-spam
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` and `xargs`, e.g.:

```
find /var/spool/postfix/maildrop -user web2 -print0 -type f | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} /var/spool/postfix/temp-spam
```

You can test it by inserting `echo`:

```
find /var/spool/postfix/maildrop -user web2 -print0 -type f | xargs -0 -I{} echo mv {} /var/spool/postfix/temp-spam
```

Comment: Wow - model answer! Thank you so much. If I could vote you up 10 then I would. (Unfortunately I can't even vote you up 1 as my rep currently too low...)

Answer (score 2):

you can also do it without spawning the `xargs` using `find`'s `-exec`.

```
find /var/spool/postfix/maildrop -user THEUSER -type f -exec mv {} /var/spool/postfix/temp-spam \;
```

If you want to see the files being moved, you can add an additional `-exec` to the command:

```
find /var/spool/postfix/maildrop -user THEUSER -type f -exec ls -lah {} \; -exec mv {} /var/spool/postfix/temp-spam \;
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard command [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) lets you match files based on metadata (name, permissions, etc.) and act on them. It traverses a directory recursively. The basic syntax is `find` followed by the directory(s) to traverse, followed by match criteria, optionally followed by a command to execute (if you don't specify a command, `find` prints the matching names).

```
find /var/spool/postfix/maildrop -user web2 -exec mv -t /var/spool/postfix/temp-spam {} +
```

This executes the command `mv -t /var/spool/postfix/temp-spam …` for the matching files: `{}` is replaced by the list of all matching files (if the list is too long, `find` will execute `mv` as many times at it takes).

The `-t` option to `mv` is a GNU (Linux/Cygwin) extension. On systems that don't have it, you need to pass the file names to move first, and then the destination. The `-exec … +` action only allows passing the file names at the end of the command line, so you need to resort to other methods.

```
find /var/spool/postfix/maildrop -user web2 -exec mv {} /var/spool/postfix/temp-spam \;
```

(calls `mv` separately for each file)

```
find /var/spool/postfix/maildrop -user web2 -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" "$0"' /var/spool/postfix/temp-spam {} +
```

(uses an intermediate shell to get the arguments in the desired order)

If you are using zsh, you can use its [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to perform the same job as `find`. Here, the `u` flag to match files owned by a user.

```
mv /var/spool/postfix/maildrop/*(u:web2:) /var/spool/postfix/temp-spam
```

(Unlike the `find` commands above, this doesn't recurse into subdirectories. It isn't needed here, but if you need it, insert `**/` in the path to say “zero or more subdirectories”, e.g. `/var/spool/postfix/maildrop/**/*(u:web2:)`.)